# Who was the first US president to graduate from a public university?

Tags: united-states, education

I know that most of the presidents went to college and a major portion of those presidents were awarded degrees. Who was the first president to be a graduate of a public university?

Comment: Isn't this just trivia rather than useful historical knowledge? Are we going to have a series of questions, such as "Who was the first US president to play golf?", "How many US presidents were left-handed?", "Who was the first US president to win a Nobel Prize?"

Comment: @KillingTime It is in a way. but some people may be wondering it and it fit the Q&A format.

Comment: While I agree this is trivial, and I really don't want to see it used as a basis for other trivial questions, it is a question and has an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first president to graduate from a public university was James K. Polk, a graduate of the University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill.

Source: Various Wikipedia articles.

Comment: Source? Citation?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I don't have a single citation for this fact, but I have reviewed the college attended for the presidents in order, until I found this one.

Comment: @Benjamin: I added your (presumed) source. Is it correct?